# DrawText Refresh Problem - Text Disappears

Tags: c++, gdi, drawtext

I'm using Objective Grid and wanted to have a grid cell control that can show an icon and text. So I took RogueWave's example (https://rwkbp.makekb.com/entry/466/) and modified it as below.

Initially the text renders correctly, but if I do anything in the grid that refreshes the relevant cell, the text disappears. If I update the whole grid, or even refresh the cell by dragging it off screen and back again, the text reappears - until it disappears again. Seems like a paint or InvalidateRect problem - but I can't figure out how to fix it. Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CGXIconControl::Draw(CDC* pDC, CRect rect, ROWCOL nRow, ROWCOL nCol, const CGXStyle& style, const CGXStyle* pStandardStyle)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    BOOL b;

    ASSERT(pDC != NULL && pDC->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CDC)));
    // ASSERTION-> Invalid Device Context ->END
    ASSERT(nRow <= Grid()->GetRowCount() && nCol <= Grid()->GetColCount());
    // ASSERTION-> Cell coordinates out of range ->END
    ASSERT_VALID(pDC);
    DrawBackground(pDC, rect, style);
    pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);

    if (rect.right <= rect.left || rect.Width() <= 1 || rect.Height() <= 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    CString str = style.GetIncludeValue() ? style.GetValue() : _T("");

    CString sTxtBefore = _T("");
    CString sTxtAfter = _T("");

    int nHAlign = style.GetHorizontalAlignment();
    int nVAlign = style.GetVerticalAlignment();

    // Save these value to restore them when done drawing
    COLORREF crOldTextColor = pDC->GetTextColor();
    COLORREF crOldBkColor = pDC->GetBkColor();

    if (!style.GetEnabled())
    {
        pDC->SetTextColor(::GetSysColor(COLOR_GRAYTEXT));
    }

    CBrush Brush;
    Brush.CreateSolidBrush(style.GetEnabled() ? ::GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOWTEXT) : ::GetSysColor(COLOR_GRAYTEXT));
    LOGBRUSH lBrush = { 0 };
    Brush.GetLogBrush(&lBrush);
    CBrush* pOldBrush = (CBrush*)pDC->SelectStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);

    CPen linePen;
    linePen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, &lBrush);
    CPen* pOldPen = pDC->SelectObject(&linePen);

    // Set font bold if necessary
    CFont* pCurfont = pDC->GetCurrentFont();
    LOGFONT lf;
    CFont font;
    if (pCurfont)
    {
        pCurfont->GetLogFont(&lf);
    }

    if (style.GetFont().GetBold())
    {
        lf.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
    }
    font.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
    CFont* pOldFont = pDC->SelectObject(&font);

    int nIcoStart = str.Find(_T("#ICO"));
    if (nIcoStart == -1)
    {
        // We didn't find an icon indicator, so just draw the text
        pDC->DrawText(str, rect, DT_SINGLELINE|nHAlign|nVAlign);
    }
    else
    {
        sTxtBefore = str.Left(nIcoStart);
        CSize szBefore = pDC->GetTextExtent(sTxtBefore);

        int nIconEnd = str.Find(_T(")"), nIcoStart);
        CString strIDResource = str.Mid(nIcoStart + 5, nIconEnd - (nIcoStart + 5));
        UINT nIDResource = _ttoi(strIDResource);

        // Load the highest bit-depth available
        HICON hIcon = NULL;
        hIcon = LoadResourceIcon(nIDResource, m_nIconSize, m_nIconSize, 32);
        hIcon == NULL ? LoadResourceIcon(nIDResource, m_nIconSize, m_nIconSize, 24) : NULL;
        hIcon == NULL ? LoadResourceIcon(nIDResource, m_nIconSize, m_nIconSize, 16) : NULL;
        hIcon == NULL ? LoadResourceIcon(nIDResource, m_nIconSize, m_nIconSize, 8) : NULL;

        sTxtAfter = str.Right(str.GetLength() - nIconEnd - 1);
        CSize szAfter = pDC->GetTextExtent(sTxtAfter);

        CRect rectCell = CGXControl::GetCellRect(nRow, nCol, rect, &style);
        CRect rectBefore = rectCell;
        CRect rectAfter = rectCell;
        int nTotalWidth = szBefore.cx + m_nIconSize + szAfter.cx;

        // Calculate positions
        int nTop, nLeft;

        switch (nHAlign)
        {
            case DT_LEFT:
            {
                rectBefore.right = rectBefore.left + szBefore.cx;
                nLeft = rectBefore.right;
                rectAfter.left = nLeft + m_nIconSize;
                rectAfter.right = rectAfter.left + szAfter.cx;
            } break;

            case DT_CENTER:
            {
                rectBefore.left = (rectCell.right - rectCell.Width() / 2) - nTotalWidth / 2;
                rectBefore.right = rectBefore.left + szBefore.cx;

                nLeft = rectBefore.right;

                rectAfter.left = nLeft + m_nIconSize;
                rectAfter.right = rectAfter.left + szAfter.cx;
            } break;

            case DT_RIGHT:
            {
                // Work from the right
                rectAfter.right = rectCell.right;
                rectAfter.left = rectAfter.right - szAfter.cx;
                nLeft = rectAfter.left - m_nIconSize;
                rectBefore.right = nLeft;
                rectBefore.left = rectBefore.right - szBefore.cx;
            } break;
        }

        switch (nVAlign)
        {
            case DT_TOP:
                nTop = rectCell.top;
                break;

            case DT_VCENTER:
                nTop = rectCell.top + (rectCell.Height() / 2 - m_nIconSize / 2);
                break;

            case DT_BOTTOM:
                nTop = rectCell.bottom - m_nIconSize;
                break;
        }

        if (!sTxtBefore.IsEmpty())
        {
            pDC->DrawText(sTxtBefore, rectBefore, DT_SINGLELINE|nHAlign|nVAlign);
        }

        b = ::DrawIconEx(pDC->m_hDC, nLeft, nTop, hIcon, m_nIconSize, m_nIconSize, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);
        b = ::DestroyIcon(hIcon);

        if (!sTxtAfter.IsEmpty())
        {
            pDC->DrawText(sTxtAfter, rectAfter, DT_SINGLELINE|nHAlign|nVAlign);
        }
    }

    // Reset original values
    pDC->SetTextColor(crOldTextColor);
    pDC->SetBkColor(crOldBkColor);
    pDC->SelectObject(pOldBrush);
    pDC->SelectObject(pOldPen);
    pDC->SelectObject(pOldFont);

    // Child Controls: spin-buttons, hotspot, combobox btn, ...
    CGXControl::Draw(pDC, rect, nRow, nCol, style, pStandardStyle);
}
```

Comment: remove all this code, simply drawtext "hello" with the default font, brushes and pens, does it still happen? If so, then it's probably not something with this specific code.

Comment: try removing ```CBrush* pOldBrush = (CBrush*)pDC->SelectStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);``` and just getting brush from DC

Comment: In situations that regard user interaction and/or painting, I `::Beep` the events to not affect the focus (eventually lost by hitting a breakpoint and ending up in IDE) nor affect the inner Windows paint mechanism (by again ending up in IDE). Maybe you can also track down the problem by "listening" to what events are fired before the painting "disappears." Unfortunately, not all modern machines can use the PC speaker "in real time," so the beeps produced may come out with delay.